# In BASH, how do I use defaults write on a plist for a existing element in an array?

Tags: macos, bash, plist

I want to change the value of `DEFAULT_VALUE_PLACEHOLDER` in the following plist using the command line tool [`defaults`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/defaults.1.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>PreferenceSpecifiers</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>DefaultValue</key>
            <string>DEFAULT_VALUE_PLACEHOLDER</string>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSTitleValueSpecifier</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Version</string>
            <key>Key</key>
            <string>prefs_item_version_title</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>StringsTable</key>
    <string>Root</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I realise that a simple find and replace will do it (e.g. sed), however, I want a more robust way of doing it.

I think is something like this, but [the documentation for the syntax](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/defaults.1.html) isn't good enough.

```
defaults write $PLIST_PATH  'PreferenceSpecifiers { 1 = { DefaultValue = $NEW_DETAULT_VALUE; }; }'
```

Comment: using objective-c / cocoa ?

Comment: No sorry should have made that clear, BASH for CI server, not in objective-c.  Ill edit the quesiton.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to do this with `defaults` (that isn't completely ugly) -- you're better off doing things like this with PlistBuddy instead:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "set :PreferenceSpecifiers:0:DefaultValue '$NEW_DEFAULT_VALUE'" "$PLIST_PATH"
```

Note that unlike `defaults`, PlistBuddy expects the filename you give it to include the ".plist"; also, (as seen above), array indexes start at 0.