# Can defaults write go more than one key deep?

Tags: macos, terminal, plist, default, opencore

I want to create a defaults write command go 2 levels deep, but can't find anything online.

The closest I got was 1 level deep using the -dict switch.

I want to script my OC update, so a lot of people could probably use this method, if I can get it to work, it would be a lot better than swapping the whole file in and out.

for example;
defaults write ~/Desktop/config Kernel -dict Emulate -dict Cpuid1Mask -data AAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAA==

the second use of the -dict doesn't work, but this is what I am trying for...

I've tried just about everything I can think of, but can't get the syntax correct.

Maybe defaults write can't handle it, but I would like to do this with the defaults write command, and not have to install another command line tool.

I want to be able to change these values;

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Kernel</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Emulate</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Cpuid1Mask</key>
            <data>
            AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==
            </data>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>PlatformInfo</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UpdateSMBIOS</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Use `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy` instead of `defaults` -- see my answer to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355850/in-bash-how-do-i-use-defaults-write-on-a-plist-for-a-existing-element-in-an-arr).

Comment: Thanks, I have gotten a lot further, but not quite there yet. I was able to figure out the true/false key, a little fighting, because it was always false, and I found on another thread that you don't specify the data type with set. The thing I can't get working now is the data. There's nothing I can find or figure out the format. No matter what I enter, it comes out wrong. How would I enter;  /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :Kernel:Emulate:Cpuid1Mask AAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAAAAA==" ~/Desktop/test.plist

Comment: I want to toggle between 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==' and 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAAAAA==', I've tried with and without single quotes, tried to print it to see the terminal output, but it prints blank. defaults write enters it into a plist as is, but PlistBuddy is masking it.

Answer (score 0):

If you encode all of it in the plist format you can do this:

```
defaults write ~/Desktop/config '<dict><key>Kernel</key><dict><key>Emulate</key><dict><key>Cpuid1Mask</key><data>AAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAA==</data></dict></dict><key>PlatformInfo</key><dict><key>UpdateSMBIOS</key><true/></dict></dict>'
```

If you want to format the plist nicely:

```
defaults write ~/Desktop/config '<dict>
  <key>Kernel</key>
  <dict>
    <key>Emulate</key>
    <dict>
      <key>Cpuid1Mask</key>
      <data>AAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAA==</data>
    </dict>
  </dict>
  <key>PlatformInfo</key>
  <dict>
    <key>UpdateSMBIOS</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</dict>'
```

---

If you're only trying to write the `Kernel` dict:

```
defaults write ~/Desktop/config Kernel '<dict><key>Emulate</key><dict><key>Cpuid1Mask</key><data>AAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAA==</data></dict></dict>'
```

If you want to format the plist nicely:

```
defaults write ~/Desktop/config Kernel '<dict>
    <key>Emulate</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Cpuid1Mask</key>
        <data>AAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAA==</data>
    </dict>
</dict>'
```